# Change color dynamically using ngClass or ngStyle in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I would like to know how to change the color on click when we have a class defined in the css file? should we use ngClass or ngStyle?

Thanks in advance.

**Css file**

```
.text-color: {
 color:red;
}
```

**html**

```
<div>
 <p>
  some text...
 </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Either would work. `ngClass` changes a class (to which you can apply CSS), and `ngStyle` changes CSS directly inline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just bind to the HTML property instead:

```html
<div (click)="divClicked = !divClicked">
 <p [class.text-color]="divClicked">
  some text...
 </p>
</div>
```

in your component, create the class property to track the state of the click:

```js
divClicked = false
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngstyle-examples-1nt6dh?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Answer (score 2):

**codeSolution**:https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngstyle-examples-m7sifc?file=src/app/app.component.html

html

```
<p [ngStyle]="{ color: colorFlag }">top</p>
<button (click)="change()">click</button>
```

ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  colorFlag = 'red';
  change(){
  this.colorFlag= 'green';
  }
}
```

**explination:**
onclick of button color of p tag will change to green , by default it will be red

Answer (score 1):

If you are using class, compliant solution:

```
<div
  <p [ngClass]="{'text-red': true, 'text-white': false}"> 
    some text...
  </p>
</div>
```

with class on your css file

```
.text-red: { 
   color:red;
}
.text-white: { 
   color:white;
}
```